# Как сохранить себе файл по ссылке

Tags: php

Как сохранить файл к себе на хостинг по ссылке, находящейся в открытом доступе? Формат xml

http://topnlab.ru/export/main/database/?data=objects&format=yandex&type=new&id=766344&key=XVWCFLzOZ9hrkJLItQ==

Если нажать правой кнопкой мыши на неё и выбрать "сохранить ссылку как..." тогда она скачивается (как ссылка на этом сайте http://sro-gosst.ru/ ). Как сделать так, чтобы просто прописать ссылку и документ загружался на хостинг.

Comment: я если честно не понял. особенно не понял при чем тут `yml`. Скачайте файла по ссылке да закиньте на хостинг по  ftp.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Ну, если задача была такая то я бы сформулировал её иначе. В результате процесс будет автоматизирован. Загвоздка в том, что незнаю, как закачать файл на сайт кодом?

Comment: Куда прописывать ссылку собираетесь?

Comment: В переменную. Сначала я реализовал данную задачу через функцию simplexml_load_file, но если файл оказывался слишком большой например по 500мб, то следовательно сервер обрывает связь так как слишком долго держу 502 ошибка. Поэтому я подумал, что лучше сначала разгрузить файлы к себе на сервер, а потом с ними работать, возник вопрос как это сделать, если есть только ссылка на xml.

Comment: мне кажется, `simplexml` в принципе умрет от файла в 500Мбайт. парсеры в целом на два вида деляться. Одни, как simpleXML, строят DOM-модель документа в памяти (т.е. целиком загружают) его. Прочитать в память 500метров и создать для этого модель вам мало какой хостинг позволит. В любом случае это будет адски долго. Вам нужен SAX парсер, эта категория просто последовательно читает файл и генерирует события, когда например, встречает тэг. Они не строят модель и не потребляют много памяти, вот вам лучше в эту сторону смотреть.

Comment: про SAX это [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlreader.php)

Comment: Спасибо за совет ! Попробую двигаться и в том направление также, ознакомлюсь с мануалом.

Answer (score 1):

Если делать это на php, то можно использовать [следуйщий код](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php):

```
<?php
$file='http://topnlab.ru/export/main/database/?data=objects&format=yandex&type=new&id=766344&key=XVWCFLzOZ9hrkJLItQ==';

$host=__DIR__.'/new.xml';
copy($file, $host);
chmod($host, 0777);
```

Через `copy` работает без проблем, я проверил.
Для автоматизации рекомендую обратить внимание на то, как [удалять](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php) старый файл.

Comment: Всё работает, тем кто воспользуется данным кодом, прошу обратить внимание на права доступа к папке.